# Vue components can't resolve each other after export as library

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently building a component library. Inside it, I register all my components globally.

Some of these components use each other. For instance, `my-menu` uses `my-button`.

This works fine in development.

When I export it as a library, and import it in another project, both of these components become available to the new project, and I can use them individually.

However, the components inside the library cannot resolve each other. So when I use `my-menu`, I get the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <my-button> - did you register 
the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure 
to provide the "name" option.
```

I am using Vue CLI and exporting as CommonJS.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have this been resolved?